# Comment function: undefined method `comment' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a function for comments for my rails application. Therefore only the `current_user` or an admin (I use active_admin) should be able to delete his comment. But I have trouble to figure that one out because my methods seem to point to `nil`. Can someone help me out, please?

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create 
    @post =Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment =@post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy 
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment= @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private
  def correct_user
    @user= User.find(current_user.id)
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.id == @post.comment.user.id
  end

end
```

In my correct_user method the undefined comment shows up, so i already tried to add

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])    
@comment= @post.comments.find(params[:id])
```

and tried different ways to make this run.

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  has_attached_file :image  #, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => 
  "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts

 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  
end
```

PS: I want to do this rather with a before action, then with an if-statement around the delete link.

Comment: You definitely should load the `@post` before using. When you make `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`, what does it happens? Don't the error change?

Comment: Is the `params[:post_id]` coming correctly in the controller?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata If i add what i said, then it tells me i had no show definition. In order to that, i added one but this isnt really a solution for me.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata  for my normal post_controller.rb the params work fine. but how can i control this. Also if i create a new Comment in the console, and doing valid? and errors.messages. it gives me also an undefined method error

Comment: If it is trying to redirect to `post_path` (which should be `show` for `post` controller), it is working.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata Ok well its definitely redirecting, if i say that everyone is allowed to use destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@post` in `#correct_user` is `nil` since it's first set inside of `#destroy`. In addition, your `Comment` model does not currently have a relation with the `User` model, `@post.comment.user.id` won't work since `#user` will be undefined as well.

To correct this, add a relation between `Comment` and `User` only call `@comment.destroy` when the right user is calling the `destroy` action.

Comment: i already tried to add  `belongs_to :user` to my comment.rb but if i do i cant create comments anymore.

Comment: You need to also add the user as a parameter to `@post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))`, then you're able to create comments again.

Comment: like `@post.comments.create(params[:comment , :user].permit(:name, :body))`? it gives me a wrong number of arguments error

Comment: Try `@post.comments.create(params[:comment , :user].permit(:name, :body).merge(user: current_user)`.

Comment: still have a wrong number of arguments within the create()

Comment: That's because I copied your typo :) Remove the `, :user` part and you're good :)

Comment: Thank you very much, commenting is possible. But i still cant delete. maybe i did something wrong. i wrapped `if current_user == @comment.user` arround `@comment.destroy`

Comment: Is `current_user == @comment.user` true at all? Did you recreate the comment you're trying to delete with an attached user?

Comment: I tried it with `current_user.id  == @comment.user_id` and this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 def destroy 
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private
  def correct_user
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @post = @comment.try(:post)
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.id == @post.try(:user_id)
  end
```

Here in `params[:id]` we are getting comment's id. Also this `@comment.try(:post)` and `@post.try(:user_id)` will work only if have associations as mentioned in your question.

```
Comment Model
belongs_to :post

Post Model
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working, but it seems like `current_user.id == @post.try(:user_id)` is not true, so i always get redirected to the root.

Comment: If you have association `belongs_to :user` in your `Comment` model then you can try `current_user.id == @comment.try(:user_id)`